# Execute multiple windows cmd commands and store process result

Tags: php

I want to write a php code to automate the below mentioned process.

Process in Windows Command prompt for each file:

1. Go to specific folder say "x", by "cd x's folder path"
2. Run command `run-all.bat RelativePath+filename.php`
3. Analysis the result produced.

I have around thousand's of files and if I do it manually then it will take a while. I took folder path input from the user, then accessed each file.

To execute the command, used `exec` function of php, but don't know how to specify "cd folder path and run-all.bat" in a single line, as if we are not inside the specific folder "x" the command run-all will not be executed.

For the third step, I think the somehow array output (second parameter can be used).

Any help/suggestion are appreciated as I'm a newbie to php?

Comment: What if you did `chdir('/path/to/x');` before calling `exec('run-all.bat');`, would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

guess this is what you are looking to accomplish ?

```
exec ('c:\\somefolder\\run-all.bat RelativePath\\filename.php', $output);
```